# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que quede seleccionado un valor del select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

quisiera saber como puedo pasar un valor al select y este quede seleccionado de acuerdo al valor que le envie porque estoy tratando de hacer un actualizar.

Este ajax llama a un método "MantProyecto.cargaCombo2()" que imprime código html(select) dentro de un "div" la cantidad de veces que indique el bucle **json.data.length** pero yo quiero pasarle un valor en especifico por cada select creado para que quede el **option** seleccionado al valor que le indique esta es la linea de codigo comentada:

el valor que le envío es json.data[i].Sub_Catalogo_id; pero quiero que ese valor que pase el valor a los demás select y no al primer select.

> //document.getElementById("idDepreciacion").selectedIndex =
>   json.data[i].Sub_Catalogo_id;

```
$.ajax({
                    url: root + 'MantProyecto/ListaTipoDepSel',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { id: JSON.stringify(parametro) },
                    success: function (json) {
                        console.log(json.data[0].Sub_Catalogo_id);
                        for (let i = 0; i < json.data.length; i++) {
                            MantProyecto.cargaCombo2();
                            //document.getElementById("idDepreciacion").selectedIndex = json.data[i].Sub_Catalogo_id;
                        }
                        $("#items2 div").remove();
                        $('#exampleModal2').modal('toggle');
                    }
                })
```

Este el método que crea el select y lo imprime en un contenedor "div" llamado items "MantProyecto.cargaCombo2()"

```
cargaCombo2: function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: root + 'MantProyecto/CargarTipoDepreciacion',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (json) {
                    //$("#items2").append("");
                    var items = document.getElementById("items2");

                    //items.innerHTML += "";
                    var select = `
                            <div class="form-row dep_val" style="margin-bottom:3px;">
                                <select id="idDepreciacion">
                            `;
                    for (let valor of json.data) {
                        select += "<option value='" + valor.id_sub_catalogo + "'>" + valor.descripcion_breve + "</option>";
                    }
                    var html = select + `</select> &nbsp;
                                        <input class="form-control col-md-2 valor" type="number" required/>  &nbsp;     
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary delete">-</button>
                                        </div>`;
                    $("#items2").append(html);

                }
            })
        }
```

En conclusión lo que deseo es que los select deberían quedar seleccionados de acuerdo al valor dado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No es claro tu planteamiento del problema. He entendido que usas un JSON para crear las opciones del `select`. Pregunto: ¿entre los datos hay algo que identifique cuál opción debe quedar seleccionada? Debes entonces usar esa información para poner `selected` al momento de crear el elemento HTML aquí en el bucle: `for (let valor of json.data) {` ahí debes preguntar y agregar `selected` cuando la condición se cumpla. Es todo.

Comment: este es el valor al cualquier quiero cambiar json.data[i].Sub_Catalogo_id que va a recibir varios valores de acuerdo a la cantidad de select que se hayan creado.

Comment: document.getElementById("idDepreciacion").selectedIndex = 3  selected document.getElementById("idDepreciacion").selectedIndex = 1 selected document.getElementById("idDepreciacion").selectedIndex = 2 selected

Comment: quiero que cada valor que recibe del json = json.data[i].Sub_Catalogo_id vaya asignandose a los diferentes select que hay.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
                    url: root + 'MantProyecto/ListaTipoDepSel',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { id: JSON.stringify(parametro) },
                    success: function (json) {
                        console.log(json.data[0].Sub_Catalogo_id);
                        for (let i = 0; i < json.data.length; i++) {
                            MantProyecto.cargaCombo2(json.data);
                            //document.getElementById("idDepreciacion").selectedIndex = json.data[i].Sub_Catalogo_id;
                        }
                        $("#items2 div").remove();
                        $('#exampleModal2').modal('toggle');
                    }
                })



cargaCombo2: function (lista) {
            $.ajax({
                url: root + 'MantProyecto/CargarTipoDepreciacion',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (json) {
                    //$("#items2").append("");
                    var items = document.getElementById("items2");

                    //items.innerHTML += "";
                    var select = `
                            <div class="form-row dep_val" style="margin-bottom:3px;">
                                <select class="idDepreciacion">
                            `;
                    for (let valor of json.data) {
                        select += "<option value='" + valor.id_sub_catalogo + "'>" + valor.descripcion_breve + "</option>";
                    }
                    var html = select + `</select> &nbsp;
                                        <input class="form-control col-md-2 valor" type="number" required/>  &nbsp;     
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary delete">-</button>
                                        </div>`;
                    $("#items2").append(html);


    for(let i=0;i<lista.length;i++){
        $(".idDepreciacion:eq('"+i+"')").val(lista[i].Sub_Catalogo_id);
        $(".valor:eq('"+i+"')").val(lista[i].Valor);
                            } 
                }
            })
        }
```

Comment: Hola, para agregar mas información a tu pregunta no uses la sección de respuestas, emplea la opción de editar en tu pregunta.

Comment: encontré la solución a mi pregunta por ello mismo la conteste nota el código que agregue.

Comment: Sería bueno que indicaras qué es lo que ha cambiado en ese código, y por qué o cómo solucionar el problema de la pregunta. Las publicaciones que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad y no suelen ser de ayuda para otros usuarios. Lee [answer] para más información.

Comment: estimado @AlvaroMontoro ya fue solucionada la pregunta.

Comment: @Dum lo sé y me alegro de que encontraras la solución. Pero si otra persona se encuentra con un problema similar, y solo se encuentra con tu respuesta que es código sin más, le va a costar mucho entender cuál era el problema y cómo lo solucionaste. Por favor, lee sobre [answer] y Edita tu respuesta para añadir más detalle.